# How do I assign a period to a Data Element Group?

Tags: dhis2

How do I assign a period to a Data Element Group in DHIS2?

My data entry screen allows for input of weekly data across several years. Data was imported for the period 2005-2012; then data has been entered directly into the system from 2013 and is still ongoing. Data that was imported for 2010 and 2011 is incorrect and needs to be corrected. However, several of these previous years are not showing in the drop down selection for "Period" in the Data Entry screen.

I can use PivotTable to view the data but I am unable to modify it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's regarding typing in data (in a software program?) and/or It involves fixing a programming based issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply click the "prev" button in the data entry screen to load additional previous years.

[image: Data entry]

Comment: Do you have a screenshot to help perchance?

Comment: Added screenshot now.

Answer (score -2):

Data set has the frequency of collection. It cannot be assigned to period.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more explanation for this? How do you know it cannot be assigned? Do you have any references?